# Application publish history

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, publish

I have a Windows Forms Application and I would like to get the publish history, ie. Date and version number of each release.

I am using the Publish function of VS and auto-increment version number on each new release/publish.  It publishes to a shared network drive for auto-update on client machines.

Does Visual Studio log the date and version of each publish?

Comment: Right mouse click the executable and select Properties, look at the Details tab.

Comment: Record your publishings in Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: How do you publish? (Do use some form of continuous build/integration/deployment pipeline?)

Comment: Yes via VS Publish to a shared drive and auto check for updates on client machines.

Comment: OK, so you update your version control with your new version number each time?

Comment: Yes, under Project > Properties and then on the Publish tab the publish version number increments automatically each time i publish a new version/release.

Comment: What about labeling your code?

Comment: What about Visual Studio keeping record of it via their own integrated versioning control?  I comment throughout my code, but don't track the version number and dates, thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess I'll just go back to my own versioning system that I built and used prior to giving the VS Publish feature a try.  You're a huge help T.S., the attitude is top notch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are using ClickOnce Deployment,

When you publish a new version of your application, Visual Studio create a new sub-folder (labeld with the version number) with the compiled code (executable and dll) and update a manifest file.

So you have a sort of tracking for the version of your application (but not of your code/development project).

Comment: Thank you Marco, I see the folders now out in the shared drive.  That is perfect, I will write a quick routine to grab the version and date from there.  That is what I needed!